# Overflow issue in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

i have an iframe on my page and seem to be facing somewhat common issue...
E 
Actually there are 2 iframes ...
1. Header iframe which has table with some columns...
2. Content iframe which has table with column data..

Now the 2 iframe tables are aligned vertically...

The alignment works fine if the columns are less and there is no scrollbar in the 2nd iframe..

But if the columns increase, I get a horizontal scrollbar in "only" the content iframe and as i scroll it I have a sync JS which scrolls the top iframe as well..Now at the end bcoz of the scrollbars occupying space, the vertical alignment gets disturbed..

As this seems to be a typical issue, does anyone have asolution which would be really helpful. I am open to CSS/Js approach as well..Thank you..

Comment: Could you give us a piece of code of where your would like to implement it? What is your reason behind using two iframes for this?

Comment: Why don't you make the bottom iframe larger to account for the scroll bar and have the content float left?

Comment: Well..it is dynamic..i.e the no of cols..so if i make the bottom iframe larger, it won't look correct in cases where no. Of cols are less w/o scrollbars..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could adjust the height of the iframe if the scrollbars are present, just check the iframes scrollWidth against it's offsetWidth and if the scroll width is higher, increase the height of the iframe by the height of the scrollbar, prolly 5-10px, I'd have to check to be sure.

Something like:

```
$('#my_frame).ready(function(){
  if(this.scrollWidth>this.offsetWidth){
    $(this).css({height:'+=10'});
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have got the issue correctly..is ther any online code ref which u can provide..

Comment: So basically the Above code would check for scrollbar presence and accordingly adjust width/height...

Comment: Oh k..so it is kind of increasing the overall width/height of the iframe...can we instead adjust width of last filler/blank column..

Comment: yes but you haven't posted any html so I don't know what element you want to edit

Comment: Ok..np..so i need to write this code in the main page or the iframe page?